# Nodemon with docker error - Internal watch failed: EIO: i/o error, lstat

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, backend, nodemon

[Here is the error. Others files are also causing the same error, every time i compose up its a different file causing the same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWFJe.png)

Hello ! im working on this project, which im using docker with 3 services: backend, frontend and database. Database is being used with prisma and i was using it normally before this problem.

Not sure if its relevant, but my laptop only have 8gb of ram, sometimes it gets near the 100% of ram.

My goal is just to update backend container every time i make changes on backend files.

Docker compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  # adminer:
  #   image: adminer
  #   restart: always
  #   ports:
  #     - 8080:8080
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./Backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./Backend:/app
    command: nodemon -L index.ts
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=itm-db
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./Frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - './Frontend:/app'
      
volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

I also tried to trigger the command "nodemon -L index.ts" on CMD of dockerfile.

Soo, how should be the way to update the backend container when changes are made locally ?